# How To Get Value From another Activity?

Tags: android

I want to Set value in a Resigter Model. I want to create a SignUp Activity in four Step. I want to know how to set value in Register Model. And I have to Get that value from anywhere.

**Here is my code** All Values are placed in one Activity. And I want to make Four Step

```
public void UploadData(final String link) {

    Response = "";

    try {

        HttpResponse response;

        Log.d("pre_link", "pre_link = " + link);

        final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        final HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(link);

        /*httppost.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic "
                + Base64.encodeToString(("username" + ":"
                        + "password").getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));*/

        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        String FullName = fullName.getText().toString();
        String UserName = userName.getText().toString();
        String DateOfBirth = dob.getText().toString();
        String Age = age.getText().toString();

        String Sex = gender.getText().toString();
        String InterestedIn = interestIn.getText().toString();
        String ToMeet = "both";//toMeet.getText().toString();

        String Email = email.getText().toString();
        String Password = pwd.getText().toString();
        String Lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
        String Long = String.valueOf(longitude);

        mpEntity.addPart("fullName", new StringBody(FullName));
        mpEntity.addPart("userName", new StringBody(UserName));
        mpEntity.addPart("dob", new StringBody(DateOfBirth));
        mpEntity.addPart("age", new StringBody(Age));
        mpEntity.addPart("gender", new StringBody(Sex));
        mpEntity.addPart("interestIn", new StringBody(InterestedIn));
        mpEntity.addPart("toMeet", new StringBody(ToMeet));
        mpEntity.addPart("email", new StringBody(Email));
        mpEntity.addPart("pwd", new StringBody(Password));

        mpEntity.addPart("latitude", new StringBody(Lat));
        mpEntity.addPart("longitude", new StringBody(Long));

        if (bab1 != null) {
            mpEntity.addPart("uploaded_file", bab1);
        }

        httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);

        createCancelProgressDialog("Uploading Image", "Please wait...", "Cancel");

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    HttpResponse response;
                    Message msg = new Message();

                    msg.what = 1;

                    try {
                        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                        if (resEntity != null) {
                            Response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity)
                                    .trim();

                            Log.d("Response", "Response = " + Response);

                            Message msg2 = new Message();
                            msg2.what = 1;
                            UpdateHandler.sendMessage(msg2);

                        }
                        if (resEntity != null) {
                            resEntity.consumeContent();
                        }
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        }.start();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Handler UpdateHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        switch (msg.what) {
        case 1:
            try {

                cancelDialog.dismiss();
                cancelDialog.hide();

                Log.d("Response", "Response = " + Response);

                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"you are Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                RegisterModel register =new RegisterModel();
                //register.setfullName();

                          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignupSuccessfully.class);

                         // i.putExtra("pwd",pwsd);
                          startActivity(i);
                          finish();
                        //flag=1;




                //String read_data = ReadDataFromAppCache(MainActivity.this, "file_name");
                //StoreDataToAppCache(MainActivity.this, "file data", "file_name");                 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
};

ProgressDialog cancelDialog = null;

private void createCancelProgressDialog(String title, String message,
        String buttonText) {
    cancelDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignUp.this);
    cancelDialog.setTitle(title);
    cancelDialog.setMessage(message);
    cancelDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    // cancelDialog2.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);

    /*cancelDialog.setButton(buttonText,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    cancelDialog.dismiss();
                    cancelDialog.hide();
                    return;
                }
            });*/
    cancelDialog.show();
}

public Bitmap setBitmap(String _path) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    //options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    ExifInterface exif;
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);

        exif = new ExifInterface(_path);
        int exifOrientation = exif
                .getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        int rotate = 0;

        switch (exifOrientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            rotate = 90;
            break;

        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            rotate = 180;
            break;

        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            rotate = 270;
            break;
        }

        //Log.d("image_rotation", "image_rotation = " + rotate);

        if (rotate != 0) {
            int w = bitmap.getWidth();
            int h = bitmap.getHeight();

            // Setting pre rotate
            Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
            mtx.preRotate(rotate);

            // Rotating Bitmap & convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
            bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        } 

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bitmap;
}

public String ReadDataFromAppCache(Context context, String file_name) {

    String output = "";
    Log.d("file name", "file name = " + file_name);
    try {
        int ch;
        File f = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/" + file_name);
        //Log.d("file path", "" + f.getAbsolutePath());

        StringBuffer strContent = new StringBuffer("");
        FileInputStream fin = null;

        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(f);

            while ((ch = fin.read()) != -1)
                strContent.append((char) ch);

            fin.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //Log.d("File " + f.getAbsolutePath(), " could not be found on filesystem");
            output = "null";
            return output;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            //Log.d("Exception while reading the file", "Exception while reading the file" + ioe);
        }

        try {
            output = URLDecoder.decode(strContent.toString(), "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) { }

        //Log.d("This is xml", "This is xml" + strContent);

        //output = strContent.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return output;
}

public void StoreDataToAppCache(Context con, String fileData, String file_name) {
    try {
        String encodedValue = "";
        try {
            encodedValue = URLEncoder.encode(fileData, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        }

        //encodedValue = sBody;
        //Log.d("store text", "store_text = " + encodedValue);
        File f = new File(con.getFilesDir() + "/" + file_name);

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(f);
        writer.append(encodedValue);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        Log.d("save complete", "save complete");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Can you Please tell me how to set these Value in Registers,
then I will create Four Step Of Signup.

Comment: You can get it through pass data using Bundle with Activity.

Comment: What is Anywhere here? :)

Comment: If you want to access value anywhere then you need to save that data in **SharedPreferences**.

Comment: Last Step Of Sign up Page ..that will be anyWhere ..i have To Make

Comment: You want to send data in SignupSuccessfully.class?

Comment: Piyush Anywhere mean I want TO Make SighUp Of Four Activity ..Of These Value i want to pass Those Value which I filled In Previous Activity

Comment: Piyush is right then. You can use shared preferences then.

Comment: Best Option http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: @beserk ..SighupSuccesfull.class Is not Correct That One Are Not Required I want Make Signup In Four Step ...So how To Set value IN A model ..From Where i Can Get Those Value Whichh I filled

Comment: @user3709878 After saved your data in SharedPreferences you can retrieve it from SharedPreferences anywhere in your activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using one of the following methods

1. Use Shared Preferences to save your data and you can access it from anywhere in the application (recommended).
2. If you have more data to be stored, I recommend using database.
3. You can pass the values from one activity to another using `intent.putExtra()` method. But you will have to do this for all new Activities
4. Another simple method is to make your variables public static and access the data using static reference from any where in your project. (not recommended).

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: thanks anu For Reply ..
I want to tell How i Want to Set Step 
1 Activity : Gender Male or Female  click On Next
2 activity:Intreste ....... click Next 
3 age  .......

Comment: ok then you keep on passing the values through the intent to the Activity2 from Activity 1. Then in the activity, where you finish the registration process, save the values in shared preference. So that you can access them from anywhere in your project even after finishing the registration activities.

Comment: is THere ANy Best Tutarial TO learn About Shared PRefrnce  and Understandable Easly

Comment: Can String Male="Male";    Editor.PutString("Male",Male)
         editor.comit(); ..INTENT   inside the Click View .Will It be Store Through Shared Prefrence Can I use These Value

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Just pass the data**

if you want to just pass data from one activity to another than you can do like this

```
startActivity(new Intent(Context,Activity_name.class).putExtra("Key",Value));
```

and get in next Activity like

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
variable = = intent.getXXXExtra("Key");
```

**Option 2 Save data in to SharedPreferences**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putXXX("Key", Value);
editor.commit();
```

and get data from it

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Variable = getResources().getInteger("Key");
```

Comment: Thnx andruboy ...i m Using api Websevice ..I have to post THose Value To Server By Post Methode ....

Comment: where is the problem ?? where you stuck ?

Comment: i m going To MAke Signup Process In Four Step ..
1 Gender : have to Use Check Box male /female
2:intrested ..Three Check Box  three Check Box 
These Value Will USe In LAst Step To Post Server

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to pass value from one activity to another activity like shared preference, bundle,intent putextra, database.. for a beginner you can use the shared preference.. i hope this will help you..

**1.Following tutorial may help you:**

[Basic Tutorial for shared preference(Login and register form)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=riyMQiHY3V4)

[Simple example for shared preference with source code](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/)